# VS2012 std::function operator bool returns true unexpectedly

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, signature, std-function

I have come across a strange behavior in VS2012 with std::function that I couldn't find anything about online.

Given the following sample program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function< int()> fntype;

void foo(const fntype& fn)
{
    try
    {
        if(fn)
            fn();
        else
            std::cout << "fn is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::bad_function_call&)
    {
        std::cout << "fn threw anyways" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // OK
    std::function<int()> nothing;
    foo(nothing);

    // Fails
    std::function<const int()> nothing2;
    foo(nothing2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The second call to *foo()* compiles (even though the return type's const is mismatched with *fntype*.
However, *if(fn)* evaluates to true nonetheless.

The output is:

> fn is empty
>
> fn threw anyways

**Note:** In the debugger, fn is shown as *empty* in both cases

This behavior cannot be reproduced with GCC ([Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b664f1842a807420)). Here, the expected output is produced:

The output is:

> fn is empty
>
> fn is empty

Is this an issue in the VS2012 implementation of the standard library?

Is there a way to work around the issue by either
a) Have fntype::operator bool() evaluate to false in case 2 or
b) Have compilation fail due to the signature mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a 2012 bug, it does not seem to happen in 2013 [see it live](http://rextester.com/GDLZ88858) this [bugs list: 44 C++11 bugs fixed in Visual Studio 2013](http://cpprocks.com/44-c11-bugs-fixed-in-visual-studio-2013/) also mentions this was fixed in 2013 and it says:

> In some cases, the conversion could produce an incorrect result in
>   VS2012 due to the function object not being empty when it should be.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> // JetPlane derives from Plane
> function<bool(JetPlane*)> plane_ready_func = function<bool(Plane*)>();
> if (plane_ready_func)   // should yield false but doesn't
> {
>     plane_ready_func(nullptr);   // gets called and throws bad_function_call
> }
> ```

The [default constructor for std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) should create an *empty function*.

I found at least one [one bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779047) which is consistent with the bug list above.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I had come across that page before, but hadn't associated that example with the issue at hand. I'll accept this as solution since it confirms my suspicion.